# Java - Splitting a CSV file into an Array

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have managed to split a CSV file based on the commas. I did this by placing a dummy String where ever there was a ',' and then splitting based on the dummy String.

However, the CSV file contains things such as:

```
something, something, something
something, something, something
```

Therefore, where there is a new line, the last and first values of each line get merged into their own string. How can I solve this? I've tried placing my dummy string where `\n` is found to split it based on that but to no success.

Help?!

Comment: Why didn't you split directly using commas? Anyway, post a http://sscce.org/ to get better help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would strongly recommend you not reinventing the wheel :). Go with one of the already available libraries for handling CSV files, eg: [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 5):

I don't see why you need a dummy string. Why not split on comma?

```
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("file.csv"));
String line;
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
    String[] fields = line.split(",");
}
```

Comment: This doesn't help me split based on lines. That was the question.

Comment: you're supposed to read each line and split each one separately. Then you wouldn't have the problem of lines merging.

Answer (score 1):

As per the dummy strings you mentioned, it could be easily processed with the help of an existing library. I would like to recommand the open source library [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial), which procides simplfied API, significent performance and flexibility.

Just refer to few lines of code to read csv data into memory with array:

```
private static void parseCSV() throws FileNotFoundException {
    CsvParser parser = new CsvParser(new CsvParserSettings());
    List<String[]> parsedData = parser.parseAll(new FileReader("/examples/example.csv"));

    for (String[] row : parsedData) {
        StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        for (String col : row) {
            strBuilder.append(col).append("\t");
        }
        System.out.println(strBuilder);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

use the followin it will split lines

```
               String[] a=scanner.next().split(" ");
```