# Java: Splitting CSV file that contains multiple lines

Tags: java, arrays, string, csv

I have managed to split a CSV file based on the commas.

However, the CSV file contains things such as:

```
something, something, something

something, something, something
```

So far, I have done:

```
String[] array = str.split(",");
```

Therefore, where there is a new line, the last and first values of each line get merged into their own string. How can I solve this?

I actually want to do this, I know there are alternate ways to implement this, however.

Help?!

Comment: Show us what you already have, code-wise.

Comment: Why not add this extra to your other question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9111870/java-splitting-a-csv-file-into-an-array

Comment: *What* do you want to do? Please add an example of your input and the required output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String.split() gets an regular expression as its argument, try **"\n"** or **","** expression.

Answer (score 0):

By checking the "result" String of the separation for a new line via `string.charAt()` for example?

I don't know if `\n` gets resolved correctly, but if I remember correctly `char(10)` and/or `char(13)` were for a line break.

Answer (score 0):

Why not read the file per line and split per line. That probably a better way of doing it. It should be something like this:

```
String line;
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
 String[] wordArray = line.split(",");
 //do something with the outcome.
}
```